# Need computed height of the gridview.after databind VB.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, vb.net

I have to display the gridview (grid A) with multiple rows which has wrapped text. To align the top of the next gridview (grid B) below grid A, I need to know the rendered height of the grid A in CODEBEHIND.
Height and Offset height - NOT working!

Answer (score 0):

Question says VB.NET but tagged with C#. The short answer is you can't get the computed height server side (if we're talking about ASP.NET, I'm not 100% certain we are), because it's a client side grid. You can do this via Javascript, and there are several examples [here](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-width-height/).